# What does シンメ状態 mean?

Tags: meaning, words

I was watching a [video](https://twitter.com/mounemasu_/status/927016483170873344) and I heard this word "シンメ状態".

[image]

Somehow I believe I have heard this word before, but I still could not make any sense of it from the dictionary.

> シンメ = ???
>
> 状態 = current status; condition; situation; circumstances; state​ (from [Jisho](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B))

Was it some kind of phrase or something?

Comment: Abbreviation of シンメトリー?

Comment: ドルヲタ用語や。ワシが回答するとアヤシイさかい、誰か答えたりいな。

Comment: ^ あたしは「ドルヲタ」すらわからないｗｗ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's jargon used among Japanese アイドル fans, especially ジャニーズ fans.

シンメ is from シンメトリー ("symmetry") and initially referred to performers dancing symmetrically in the mathematical sense, like a mirror-image.

Then it gained a broader sense among idol fans, and it now mainly refers to two idols within a group who often perform together and are considered as a "pair". For example, the person in the video mentions やまちね (山田涼介 and 知念侑李), who can be considered as a シンメ in *Hey! Say! JUMP*. Most people in Japan know nothing about やまちね and シンメ, so I think the person in the video said it to show his knowledge about J組.